# Fedora / RHEL association list?

Tags: fedora, rhel

My Google-fu is failing me!

Does a list exist publicly that identifies which Major (Minor?) versions of Red Hat Enterprise Linux are spun from which Fedora versions? Does Red Hat even release that information?

Can we closely match up Fedora and RHEL versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's here buried in a table on the Fedora Project's site, on a page titled simply: [Red Hat Enterprise Linux](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux).

[image: ss#1]